# Can you turn off conditional compilation symbols from msbuild.exe command line?

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop

We have CODE_ANALYSIS defined in our C# components so that FxCop analyzes them when we build them on our development boxes. I would like to have FxCop turned off when it runs through our build system. The build system is obviously using the msbuild.exe command line command. Is there a way to modify the conditional compilation symbols from this executable? If not, does anyone know any other possible solutions to my problem (other than turning it off manually)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CODE_ANALYSIS compilation symbol controls whether the SuppressMessageAttribute instances included in the code are copied into the compiled assembly.  It does not control whether FxCop runs.  If you want to override a project-level MSBuild property like RunCodeAnalysis (which is the beastie that controls whether FxCop runs under MSBuild), you should be able to use the MSBuild.exe /property command line switch.  e.g.:

```
msbuild.exe <...> /property:RunCodeAnalysis=true
```

Comment: I found out that we are actually using a post build command to launch FxCop. Nevertheless, you answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to turn them off?  The best way to set up the project is to define CODE_ANALYSIS for debug configurations only.  The release version will not have this value set.  That way, when you build production installs, they will not have any references to FxCop.